# Can anyone think of applications of a 3 way (k-way) dot product in computer science or data mining

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have developed a locality sensitive hashing algorithm for the 3-way or k-way dot product. When I say 3-way dot product I mean the following. Suppose we have

$x,y,z \in [-1,1]^{S}$ for $S \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then the 3-way dot product is

$\sum_{i = 0}^{S}x_{i}y_{i}x_{i}$.

I was hoping to find some applications of the 3-way dot product in data mining or mining massive data sets.